# host id out of bound when use hololens as server to connect with unity editor by unet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, unity3d-unet

I want to communicate between HoloLens and unity editor by unet, following is my setting for my unetsharemanager gameobject in unity editor.

[image]

My Unity version is 2017.4.1f1. The Network Manager is the unity original Network Manager component, and my NetworkDiscoveryWithAnchors scripts is following:
https://github.com/mayoco/hello-world/blob/master/NetworkDiscoveryWithAnchors.cs

When I run in unity editor first, then run the app in HoloLens, it runs well and can communicate with each other. However, If I run the app in HoloLens first,then run the app in unity editor, an error show up:

[image]

Also, If I start another copy of my project in another unity editor and try to make them connect, the same error show up in Console of the later run unity editor.

Does anyone know where maybe wrong?

Comment: Plus, The project is HoloLens default recommend setting and the same error show up if I delete the Client prefab. Therefore, I think those parts should not have problem...

Comment: Please provide minimal working examples of your code here and not in some external link. If in the future the URL becomes invalid your content is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I use another NetworkDiscovery script and NetworkManager script and it works！ Though the same error show up, the app can keep running and work fine. Now If I run the app, It will automatically find if there are server exist in current network, if not ,start as server. Otherwise, start as client.

NetworkDiscoveryCustom.cs and NetworkManagerCustom.cs:
https://github.com/mayoco/hello-world/commit/d1cea2733369a849213ec9562162df778fc25aa4